# ¿Como puedo crear un evento tipo sheduler en azure programaticamente desde C#?

Tags: azure

Buen día,

Soy principiante en azure, anteriormente tenia un logic app

Un temporizador que ejecuta todos los días un enpoint
(mi enpoint hecho en asp net core 6) para revisar que empleados cumplen años para enviar un correo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera no revisar todos los días los empleados que cumplen años, ya que habrán mas tipos de notificaciones a enviar.

¿Que me recomiendan realizar o que servicio en azure utilizar?,
Cuando detecte que se registro un empleado que cumple años por ejemplo el 26 de diciembre. yo pueda programáticamente crear un evento tipo sheduler en azure que se pueda ser ejecutado todos los 26 de diciembre, para que llame a mi enpoit cumpleaños.

¿Alguna recomendación o documentación para realizarlo?

- Mis enpoints estan desarrollados en ASP NET CORE 6
- Mi BD esta en PostgreSQL

Comment: ¿Y si muestras código de lo que has intentado y/o investigado hasta el momento? Te regalo una idea: un simple `background service` que se ejecute todos los días a las 8am y que revise si hay algún empleado que el mismo mes y el mismo día actual coincida con el registro de su cumpleaños. De ser `True`, enviar correo.

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx pero es lo que hice con el logic app que se ejecuta todos lo días y revisa por medio de mi enpoint los que cumplen años ese mismo día.

El punto es que no quisiera estar teniendo un servicio que revise todos los dias si hay algo. ya que mis tipos de notificaciones por correo crecerá.

Hasta el momento lo que he visto es que existen Azure fuctions timer.

Pero estoy un poco confundido :/ . y quisiera alguna orientación que servicio se adecua mas a mi necesidad.

Comment: Lamentablemente, la pregunta queda basada en opiniones. Hay varias maneras de resolver el caso. Te invito a darte una vuelta por la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol  Aquí puedes hablar con libertad sobre recomendaciones. Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx lo considero. Gracias.

Comment: En tu escenario, se crearía un evento programado en memoria cada vez que se necesite. Pero si no lo persistes, de alguna forma, en un reinicio de la app, por cualquier motivo, la programación se pierde.

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras , desconozco al 100% que servicio en azure utilizaría y cual seria su comportamiento al crearlo.

He visto que existe el ARM para crear un recurso en azure, al estar consultando en internet he visto que exiten los WebJobs , AzureFuctions Trigger, Event Grid etc.

No se si podría realizar lo que requiero , o talvez haya una solucion mas simple sin estar revisando periodicamente mi base de datos.

Te agradezco.